Timeout Problem with FCM HTTPS V1: app/network-timeout Error while making request: timeout of 10000ms exceeded
I recently updated my Firebase Cloud Functions to use the new API HTTPS v1 and I am getting these errors from my Cloud Function (timestamps and token removed).  My function is called sendPushOnPostFirestore and it calls sendToDeviceWithPayload (shown below):
sendPushOnPostFirestorenm199m78x2v8 Error sending payload to token .not catch.: XXXXXXX projects/[projectname]/messages/1727722733230713

 Error sending payload to token: XXXXX FirebaseAppError: Error while making request: timeout of 10000ms exceeded.
sendPushOnPostFirestorenm199m78x2v8 at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
sendPushOnPostFirestorenm199m78x2v8 at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
sendPushOnPostFirestorenm199m78x2v8 at new FirebaseAppError (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:123:28)
sendPushOnPostFirestorenm199m78x2v8 at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/api-request.js:204:23
sendPushOnPostFirestorenm199m78x2v8 at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
sendPushOnPostFirestorenm199m78x2v8 at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
sendPushOnPostFirestorenm199m78x2v8 at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:545:9)
sendPushOnPostFirestorenm199m78x2v8 at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7) {
sendPushOnPostFirestorenm199m78x2v8 errorInfo: {
sendPushOnPostFirestorenm199m78x2v8 code: 'app/network-timeout',
sendPushOnPostFirestorenm199m78x2v8 message: 'Error while making request: timeout of 10000ms exceeded.'
sendPushOnPostFirestorenm199m78x2v8 },
sendPushOnPostFirestorenm199m78x2v8 codePrefix: 'app'
sendPushOnPostFirestorenm199m78x2v8 }

But the message usually goes through anyway if I send as a generic "notification" like this:
function sendToDeviceWithPayload (token, payload, options) {
    const message = {
        "notification": {
            "title": payload.notification.title,
            "body": payload.notification.body
        },
        // "apns": {
        //     "payload": {
        //         "aps": {
        //             "alert": {
        //                 "title": payload.notification.title,
        //                 "body": payload.notification.body
        //             },
        //             "sound": "default",
        //             "badge": 1
        //         }
        //     }
        // },
        "token": token
    };

admin.messaging().send(message)
        .then (response => {
            if (response.successCount === 1) {
                console.log ("Push notification sent succesfully to:", token, response);
            } else {
                console.log ("Error sending payload to token .not catch.:", token, response);
        }})
        .catch (e => {
            console.log ("Error sending payload to token:", token, e);
            if (e.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
              e.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
            db.collection(TABLE_FCM).doc(token).delete();
            console.log ("Deleted token.")
            }
        });

But I can't send using the apns object (which means I can't update the badge, etc.) -- that won't work with the rejected token (so I commented it out for now).
Does anyone know why I am getting the timeout error?  The tokens are in the FCM database, they are retrieved properly and sent with this function (correctly, I think).  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

The error message is telling you that your code is trying to use a variable error which was never defined. It seems your error checking code isn't correct.  Maybe you meant to put it all in the catch callback where the variable e is defined?

@DougStevenson - I made the edit and it is deleting tokens that have those error messages.  Strangely, it is not deleting them all at once, but seems to delete a couple each time the function is run.  I am still getting a timeout error (which I was also getting before) - see the error in the question above.  Could it be my package.json is using firebase-admin 8.0.0?

In order to avoid confusion, you should remove the old code and error messages if they're no longer relevant to your issue. Focus on the problem at hand.

@DougStevenson - done

You're not returning a promise that resolves only after all the async work is complete.  That's absolutely required when working in Cloud Functions in order to ensure that all async work actually completes.  See the documentation for details.
